# socket disconnect acknowledgment time delay when user go offline/online

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, pooling

We are facing an problem with socket on internet switching case.
For example : An user connected to Internet **A** & switched the internet to network **B** .
When user disconnected then Socket taking time to fire socket.disconnect() event but in meanwhile User connected again to socket with new socket_id (after switching the network).

After user re-connect we also received Socket.on('disconnect') event with old socket_id but it should not be. Because user is already reconnected.

We are doing this because we have to manage the duplicate session of an user on socket.

**Is that possible if user reconnected in meanwhile time we should not received any disconnect event ?**

We are using below configuration on our server end

1. Socket Lib 2.1.1 with pooling & websocket
2. Node server with single/multi thread socket.

In single thread with **Pooling** we are facing above problem in rare case. But in multi-thread socket server, we are facing this problem each time.

But In Multi-thread with **Websocket** we are facing above problem in rare case and in single thread socket server, we are facing this problem each time.

Is that possible to increase the socket respond time ?
Socket should fire disconnect queue first before to connect an user ?
which is the best practice to use socket with Pooling or websocket in single/multi thread socket ?

Comment: Yes. No matter which library you use, it's possible for the `onclose` event to fire after the client reconnected and an `onopen` event was fired for the new connection. This is due to nature of networking and the way network failures are detected.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But here we want to disconnect particular user, who join the room.  We fire onclose  event if we want to close whole socket connections.